# Changing variables in separate Python files

Tags: python

So I just found out today that I can import variables from other Python files. For example, I can have a variable `green = 1`, and have a completely separate file use that variable. I've found that this is really helpful for functions.

So, here's my question. I'm sorry if the title didn't help very much, I wasn't entirely sure what this would be called. 
I want my program to ask the player what his or her name is. Once the player has answered, I want that variable to be stored in a separate Python file, "player_variables.py", so every time I want to say the player's name, instead of having to go to `from game import name`, I can use `from player_variables import name`, just to make it easier.

I fully understand that this is a lazy man's question, but I'm just trying to learn as much as I could. I'm still very new, and I'm sorry if this question is ridiculous. :).
Thanks for the help, I appreciate it. (be nice to me!)

Comment: Can you post some code that you've tried and describe what isn't working?

Comment: It doesn't sound as if you are on the right track. This is data that should probably be in a database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I think you're confusing some ideas about variables and the values of variables.

1) Simply creating a python file with variable names allows you to access the values of those variables defined therein. Example:

```
# myvariables.py
name = 'Steve'

# main.py
import myvariables
print myvariables.name
```

Since this requires that the variables themselves be defined as global, this solution is not ideal. See this link for more: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#global

2) However, as your question states that **you want your program to *save* the variable of some user-entered value in the python file**, that is another thing entirely as that's [metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) [in python](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Metaprogramming.html) - as your program is outputting Python code, in this case a file with the same name as your variables python file.

From the above, if this is the means by which you're accessing and updating variables values, it is a simpler idea to have a config file which can be loaded or changed at whim. **Metaprogramming is only necessary when you need it.**

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm surprised what I was trying to do could not be done, however. I will try to learn how to make a config file.

Comment: @KyleMe: You're welcome. But, you misunderstand me: it can be done - undoubtedly. But, as what you intend to do is actually more involved that what it should be, I proposed an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a data format for storing data, not a data *manipulating* programming language for this:

```
import json
import myconfig

def load_data():
    with open(myconfig.config_loc, 'r') as json_data:
        return json.loads(json_data.read())

def save_data(name, value):
    existing_data = load_data()
    existing_data[name] = value
    with open(myconfig.config_loc, 'w') as w:
        w.write(json.dumps(existing_data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

You should only store the location of this json file in your `myvariables.py` file, but I'd call it something else (in this case, `myconfig`, or just `config`).

[More on the json library can be found here.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)